# Which filter to apply in the image to remove all the objects other than vehicles

Tags: matlab

I used otsu thresh holding technique to separate the background from vehicles. Now I want to calculate the number of vehicles and when I apply my algorithm it calculates the other objects along with vehicles so I want to apply any filter that would remove other objects from the image. The image and code for otsu separation and counting of objects are shown below. Help me out in this.

Vehicles separated from road:
[image: vehicles separated from road]

My code:

```
i=imread('14.png');
figure,imshow(i);
t2=graythresh(i)
it=im2bw(i,t2)
figure,imshow(it);
c=imfill(it,'holes');
figure,imshow(c);
se=strel('disk',20);
iopenned=imopen(c,se);
figure,imshow(iopenned);
[labeled,numObjects]=bwlabel(iopenned,4);
```

Comment: you can ignore objects with too few pixels

Comment: Yuval Harpaz how to do it can you explain a little bit more

Comment: Which pic did you post? iopened?

Comment: it is 
imshow(it)

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be fine, I only changed disk size to 8, and then you have to ignore small objects, say, smaller than 1000 pixels.
Try this:

```
% set car size threshold
minCarSize = 1000;
% read image from stackoverflow
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JVK9.jpg');
it = img(31:425,83:1035,1) > 200;
% process the image with disk size 8
c = imfill(it,'holes');
se = strel('disk',8);
iopenned = imopen(c,se);
[labeled,numObjects]=bwlabel(iopenned,4);
% check object sizes
objSize = nan(numObjects,1);
loc = nan(numObjects,2);
for iObj = 1:numObjects
    objSize(iObj,1) = sum(sum(labeled == iObj));
    [loc(iObj,1),loc(iObj,2)] = find(labeled == iObj,1); % these are x-y to display car numbers
end
% select big shapes
car = find(objSize > minCarSize);
% create image with car count
carNum = insertText(uint8(iopenned*255),fliplr(loc(car,:)),regexp(num2str(1:length(car)),' *','split'));
figure
imshow(carNum);
title('iopenned + car count')
axis off
```

[image: car count]

Comment: Undefined function 'insertText' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
 i get above error when i try to run that code any help

Comment: I use matlab 2017b, maybe you don't have the function. However, it doesn't matter because this is only for displaying the results. The number of cars is length(car)

Comment: when i run your code i dont get accurate results and it just count very few cars

Comment: Try change minCarSize, I cannot help you further than that, I didn't know why the code runs differently on your computer

Comment: @YuvalHarpz can you help me with insertText function in matlab 2014a

Comment: Try this: imshow(iopenned);
text(loc(car,2),loc(car,1),regexp(num2str(1:length(car)),' *','split')','color','r')